# Importing .obj, normals appear randomly flipped

Tags: import, faces, normals

I am trying to import a .obj model in Blender. The .obj in question can be downloaded from https://poly.google.com/view/9pffFcv7LSm.

When I import the model in Blender, most of its faces look inside out. It's as if normals were randomly flipped. However, when I display the normals overlay, they all point properly outwards.

I've tried triangulating the mesh and/or recalculating normals, but so far nothing has worked.

I've attached a few pictures of the result I'm getting, but you should be able to reproduce with the link above.

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

Comment: Not sure what it is but when I create and assign a *new material* to the duck, the viewport error is gone. Might be worth reporting that as a bug: https://developer.blender.org/

Comment: @brockmann I changed the material's blend mode from alpha blend to opaque, and it appears to have fixed my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, solved it by unchecking "Show Backface" in Stettings under the Material Properties.